# Java - Including BST

Tags: java

I have this BST problem I'm trying to solve in java, but I don't know why it's not working.
Here's the problem:

- Binary search tree (BST) is a binary tree where the value of each
  node is larger or equal to the values in all the nodes in that node's
  left subtree and is smaller than the values in all the nodes in that
  node's right subtree.

  Write a function that checks if a given binary search tree contains a
  given value.

  For example, for the following tree:

  n1 (Value: 1, Left: null, Right: null) n2 (Value: 2, Left: n1, Right:
  n3) n3 (Value: 3, Left: null, Right: null) Call to contains(n2, 3)
  should return true since a tree with root at n2 contains number 3.

This is how I am trying to solve it:

```
    class Node {
    public int value;
    public Node left, right;

    public Node(int value, Node left, Node right) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

public class BinarySearchTree {
    public static boolean contains(Node root, int value) {
       if(root.value == value)
           return true;

       else if(value < root.value){
           if(root.left == null)
               return false;
           contains(root.left, value);
       }
       else if(value > root.value){
           if(root.right == null)
               return false;
           contains(root.right, value);
       }

        return false;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node n1 = new Node(1, null, null);
        Node n3 = new Node(3, null, null);
        Node n2 = new Node(2, n1, n3);

        System.out.println(contains(n2, 3));
    }
}
```

This should return true, but it doesn't... Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to say `return contains(...)`, not just call the method. Right now you're discarding the results of the recursive call, and eventually getting to the `return false;` at the end of the method.

Comment: Sure that's the reason... God I'm feeling stupid. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return contains(...)` instead of just calling `contains(...)` for those recursive calls, so that you don't lose values when they are made

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BinarySearchTree {
    public static boolean contains(Node root, int value) {
       if(root.value==value)
           return true;
        else if(value<root.value && root.left!=null)
            return contains(root.left,value);
            else if(value> root.value && root.right!=null)
                return contains(root.right,value);
                else return false;
    }
```

Comment: Explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

I have written one c++ version. It seems that it is more clear to understand.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class Node
{
public:
   Node(int value, Node* left, Node* right)
   {
      this->value = value;
      this->left = left;
      this->right = right;
   }

   int getValue() const
   {
      return value;
   }

   Node* getLeft() const
   {
      return left;
   }

   Node* getRight() const
   {
      return right;
   }

private:
   int value;
   Node* left;
   Node* right;
};
class BinarySearchTree
{
public:

   static bool isValidBST( Node& root)
   {

    if ((root.getLeft())&&(root.getValue()<=(root.getLeft()->getValue())))
        return false;
    if ((root.getRight())&&(root.getValue()>=(root.getRight()->getValue())))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (root.getRight())
    {
        if(!isValidBST(*(root.getRight()))) return false;
    }
    if(root.getLeft())
    {
        if(!isValidBST(*(root.getLeft()))) return false;
    }

    return true;

    }
};


#ifndef RunTests
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    Node n7(7, NULL, NULL);
    Node n10(11, NULL, NULL);
    Node n2(2, NULL, NULL);
    Node n5(5, NULL, NULL);
    Node n4(4, &n2, &n5);
    Node n9(9, &n7, &n10);
    Node n6(6, &n4, &n9);
    
    std::cout << BinarySearchTree::isValidBST(n6);

    return 0;
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

public class Node
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public Node Left { get; set; }

    public Node Right { get; set; }

    public Node(int value, Node left, Node right)
    {
        Value = value;
        Left = left;
        Right = right;
    }
}

public class BinarySearchTree
{
    public static bool Contains(Node root, int value)
    {
          if(root.Value == value){
            return true;
          }        
          else if(value < root.Value && root.Left !=null ){
           return Contains(root.Left,value);          
          }
          else if(value > root.Value && root.Right !=null){
            return Contains(root.Right,value);            
          }
          else{
            return false;
          }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node n1 = new Node(1, null, null);
        Node n3 = new Node(3, null, null);
        Node n2 = new Node(2, n1, n3);

        Console.WriteLine(Contains(n2, 3));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).